# Numpy array element-wise division (1/x)

Tags: python, numpy, division

My question is very simple, suppose that I have an array like

```
array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and I'd like to get an array like

```
[1, 0.5, 0.3333333, 0.25]
```

However, if you write something like

```
1/array
```

or

```
np.divide(1.0, array)
```

it won't work.

The only way I've found so far is to write something like:

```
print np.divide(np.ones_like(array)*1.0, array)
```

But I'm absolutely certains that there is a better way to do that. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: In Python 3, the above code behaves as expected and `1/array` is sufficient.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`1 / array` makes an integer division and returns `array([1, 0, 0, 0])`.

`1. / array` will cast the array to float and do the trick:

```
>>> array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 1. / array
array([ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ])
```

Comment: As an aside, if you put `from __future__ import division` at the start of your code, then it will always perform real division with integers. This is the default behaviour in Python 3, as it's the answer that most people expect. You can still get integer division using the `//` operator.

Answer (score 4):

Other possible ways to get the reciprocal of each element of an array of integers:

```
array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Using numpy's reciprocal:

```
inv = np.reciprocal(array.astype(np.float32))
```

Cast:

```
inv = 1/(array.astype(np.float32))
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried :

```
inverse=1./array
```

and that seemed to work...
The reason

```
1/array
```

doesn't work is because your array is integers and `1/<array_of_integers>` does integer division.